# Parsing a file by removing the same phrase from each line, then sorting the results alphabetically

Tags: bash, sorting, parsing, sed

Here is my input file atm and it has 1000 plus lines:

```
system="Tom Sawyer Rose"
system="A Far Coat"
system="Be Nice To Her"
system="Oh Yes"
system="Zebra Heaven"
system="O Boy"
system="Too Bad Sunny"
system="Felix Rocks"
```

I want to remove the word system, the equal sign and the quotations:

```
Tom Sawyer Rose
A Far Coat
Be Nice To Her
Oh Yes
Zebra Heaven
O Boy
Too Bad Sunny
Felix Rocks
```

Then I would like to sort them alphabetically:

```
A Far Coat
Be Nice To Her
Felix Rocks
O Boy
Oh Yes
Tom Sawyer Rose
Too Bad Sunny
Zebra Heaven
```

Comment: "StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that data `cut` and `sort` are enough when using `"` as field delimiter and extracting the second field or column:

```
$ cut -d \" -f 2 file | sort
A Far Coat
Be Nice To Her
Felix Rocks
...
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 TIMTOWTDI is a serious exaggeration. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is easily achievable using `sed` and `sort`.

```
~ $ sed 's/^system="\(.*\)"$/\1/' input.txt | sort
A Far Coat
Be Nice To Her
Felix Rocks
O Boy
Oh Yes
Tom Sawyer Rose
Too Bad Sunny
Zebra Heaven
```

**Sidenote:** Please consider looking up those tools the next time you have a similar problem, and always include your failed attempt in the question description. Otherwise you'll earn yourself downvotes because people assume you are too lazy to look for a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F"[=|\"]" '{print $3}' input | sort
```

Brief explanation,

- `-F"[=|\"]`: set the input field separator as = or "
- Print the $3 as you desired
- Pipeline the `awk` result to `sort`

Or you may also use `grep` to do that,

```
grep -oP '="\K.*(?=")' input | sort
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

**Solution 1st:** By using sub and gsub utility of awk with sort.

```
awk '{sub(/[^"]*/,"");gsub(/"/,"");print | "sort"}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
A Far Coat
Be Nice To Her
Felix Rocks
O Boy
Oh Yes
Tom Sawyer Rose
Too Bad Sunny
Zebra Heaven
```

**EDIT:** Adding explanation and non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '{
sub(/[^"]*/,""); ##Using awk default utility named sub for substitution which works on sub(/regex/,new_text/variable,line/variable), so substituting everything till first occurence of " with NULL here in current line.
gsub(/"/,"");    ##Now using gsub(globally substitution) method to remove all remaining occurrences of " with NULL in current line.
print | "sort"   ##Now using print of current line, here point to be noted | "sort" will take all the lines of Input_file and sort them(like normal sort with 1st column alphabetic order).
}
' Input_file     ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

**Solution 2nd:** By making "(string) as a field separator and then doing sort to it.

```
awk -F'"' '{print $2 | "sort"}'  Input_file
A Far Coat
Be Nice To Her
Felix Rocks
O Boy
Oh Yes
Tom Sawyer Rose
Too Bad Sunny
Zebra Heaven
```